# Calling an aws function in parallel

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, parallel-processing

I want to call my AWS function lots of times but I want to minimise the time taken so I want to do it in parallel if that is possible.

The function I want to call simply goes to a website and checks out on your behalf. I have copied and pasted this bellow.

I have looked for answers online but it seems very complicated with multi-thread or conn but no-one seems to explain what those are. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

```
import json
import requests
import time


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    def login(user_pword):
        s = requests.Session()
        credientials = {
            'userid': user_pword[0],
            'pwd': user_pword[1]
        }
        res = s.post('https://website.html', data=credientials)
        booking = {
            'event':4532,
            'date': '2022-09-08'
        }
        res = s.post('https://newWebsite', data=booking)
        print(res.content)
        pass

    login(("username", "password"))
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the current code.

Comment: @Marcin there is nothing wrong with the function I just don’t know how to call it in parallel in AWS Lambda. The function works as intended.

Comment: How do you want to call your lambda function ?

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple solution to make your lambda function run in parallel .
The simplest would be to put the request in SQS as many as you want .
Make your lambda trigger [SQS Trigger for lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) for SQS and that will start running in parallel .
You dont have to change anything in lambda .
Lets say you have 100 request in SQS .
Then depending on batch configured you might have 100 lambda or 10 lambda running in parallel .
You can verify this in lambda concurrency metrics also by yourself .